# Tell AzCopy batch to overwrite files?

Tags: azure, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, azcopy

So I'm using an AzCopy which is run manually at the moment but I was to run it through Task Scheduler on one of our servers. This copies files from one container to another and runs perfectly if I manually execute the batch file.
However, it asks me:

> Overwrite https://.file.core.windows.net// with https://.file.core.windows.net//? (Yes/No/All)

Now this is all great and if I click Yes or All is proceeds with no problems.
But if it is scheduled, I loose the ability to click Yes/All and then it hits timeout?

Is there a way or something I'm missing to allow it to continue through this please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please try it with `/Y` option. From [`AzCopy Parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-parameters):

> ## /Y
>
> Suppresses all AzCopy confirmation prompts.

Comment: The link no longer lists all of the parameters...Is there anywhere online that lists them because I cannot find it!

Comment: @OffHeGoes - Try here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy

Comment: @JoshReynolds Thanks, but that is the older version 8. I would like to see the latest :)

Comment: Works only for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

For version 10, the default behavior is to overwrite without prompt and this can be controlled by the `--overwrite` flag (default 'true').

> Overwrite the conflicting files and blobs at the destination if this
> flag is set to true. (default 'true') Possible values include 'true',
> 'false', 'prompt', and 'ifSourceNewer'. For destinations that support
> folders, conflicting folder-level properties will be overwritten this
> flag is 'true' or if a positive response is provided to the prompt.
> (default "true")

See also the [azcopy copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) page for reference.